# Resources for Riemann-Stieltjes or Lebesgue-Stieltjes integrals

Tags: lebesgue-integral, stieltjes-integral, delay-differential-equations

I'm an engineer, who works with retarded delay differential equations. So far I've encountered systems with single or multiple point-wise delays, and systems with distributed delays. Someone on a conference told me that I could unify/generalize my models using the two integrals mentioned in the title. The only problem is, that since I'm not a mathematician, I don't know what literature to look up, or where to start.

My systems so far are:

- $\dot{x}(t) = A_0x(t) + \sum_{k=1}^n A_k x(t-\tau_k), \tau_1 < \tau_2 < \dots < \tau_n, \quad x(h) = \phi(h)$ for $h \in [-\tau_n, 0]$
- $\dot{x}(t) = A_0x(t) + \int_{-\tau}^0 A_\tau(\eta) x(t+\eta)d\eta, \quad x(h) = \phi(h)$ for $h \in [-\tau, 0]$
- $\dot{x}(t) = \int_{-\tau}^0 A_\tau(\eta) x(t+\eta)d\eta, \quad x(h) = \phi(h)$ for $h \in [-\tau, 0]$

so my guess would be:
$\dot{x}(t) = \int_{-\tau}^0 dB(\eta) x(t+\eta), \quad x(h) = \phi(h)$ for $h \in [-\tau, 0]$, but in the first two cases, this $B$ would be a discontinuous function. What literature would you recommend for me to brush up on my nonexistent functional differential equations knowledge and integrals?

Comment: If you just want to start by covering integration, Rudin's PMA and Tao's analysis books cover the material at an undergraduate level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is intended just as an overview of what these integrals are and how they apply to your situation. It is not intended to tell you everything you need to know. You still need to check texts such as Andrey Yanyuk has suggested. But please feel free to be much more concerned about what the theorems say can be done with the integrals than with why the theorems are true, and all the minutia that comes with it. In particular, wherever the theorems talk about something holding "almost everywhere", you are safe to ignore that part, as for your function $x(t)$, which is continuous, it will hold everywhere.

You do not need to go study all the complexities and minutia about these integrals that we mathematicians love to delve through. The broad strokes are fine.

---

For your purposes, the advantage to these other forms of integrals is that it converts your multiple cases into a single case, so you only have to develop the theory once, not three times. I do not see any advantage to you in studying Lebesgue-Stieltjes integration. Instead I suggest either Riemann-Stieltjes integration, or straight Lebesgue integration for an abstract measure. Lebesgue-Stieltjes is just the latter, but with the measure defined in a way that mimics the integration of Riemann-Stieltjes. However, measures for your purposes are more easily and intuitively defined in other fashions.

Recall that (Riemann) integration $\int_a^b f(x)\,dx$ is defined as a limit of $\sum_{k=1}^n f(t_k)(x_k - x_{k-1})$ where $a = x_0 < x_1 < \dots < x_n = b$, and each $t_k \in [x_{k-1},x_k]$, and the limit is taken as $\max_k (x_k-x_{k-1})$ goes to $0$.

- The Riemann-Stieltjes integral $\int_a^b f(x)\,dg(x)$ is the limit of $\sum_{k=1}^n f(t_k)(g(x_k) - g(x_{k-1}))$, while the rest of the definition is unchanged.

When $g$ is differentiable, this results in $$\int_a^b f(x)\,dg(x) = \int_a^b f(x)g'(x)\,dx$$
which is nothing new. It becomes useful when $g$ isn't differentiable, or even continuous. Any function $g$ can be used, no matter how nastily behaved. What is affected by the bad behavior of $g$ is which functions $f$ can be integrated with respect to it. But $g$ itself could be anything. For your purposes, simple jump discontinuities would handle all cases. And if $f$ is continuous, it will always be integrable with respect to a $g$ that is continuous except for jump discontinuities at isolated points.

In particular, if $f$ is continuous at $0$, and $$H(x) = \begin{cases}0&x < 0\\1&x\ge 0\end{cases}$$ is the *Heaviside* function, then $$\int_a^b f(x)\,dH(x) =\begin{cases}f(0)&0 \in [a,b]\\0&0\notin [a,b]\end{cases}$$

So you can express $$\sum_{k=1}^n A_kx(t-\tau_k) + \int_{-\tau}^0A(\eta)x(t - \eta)\,d\eta = \int_{-\tau}^0x(t - \eta)\, dB(\eta)$$
where $$B(\eta) = \int_{-\tau}^\eta A(t)\,dt + \sum_{k=1}^n A_kH(\eta - \tau_k)$$
Which is why Riemann-Stieltjes simplifies and generalizes your situation.

- Lebesgue integration starts off with a *measure* $\mu$, which is a function that takes subsets of $[a,b]$ as arguments, and assigns to them a non-negative number representing their "size". You can *think* of Lebesgue integration $\int_a^b f(x)\,d\mu$ as being the limit of the sum $\sum_{k=1}^n f(t_k)\mu([x_{k-1},x_k])$. This is not how the actual Lebesgue integration is defined, but for well-behaved $f$, it amounts to the same thing, and any integrand $f$ arising from *your* problem will definitely be well-behaved.

A measure assigns a value $\ge 0$ to subsets of $[a,b]$. In general, it is not reasonable to actually define a measure value for every subset of $[a,b]$, but it will be defined on every subset you will ever have need for, so I will not worry about the difference. The key requirement of a measure is *additivity*: For all measurable sets $U$ and $V$, then $\mu(U \cup V) = \mu(U) + \mu(V) - \mu(U \cap V)$. In particular, if $U$ and $V$ do not overlap, then $\mu(U \cup V) = \mu(U) + \mu(V)$.

The *Lebesgue measure* $\lambda$ is completely definable by the requirement that for intervals $[c,d], \lambda([c,d]) = d-c$. For any Riemann-integrable function $f, \int_a^b f(x)\,dx = \int_a^b f(x)\,d\lambda$. In fact, you can think of $dx$ as just another name for $d\lambda$.

You can think of a measure $\mu$ as giving the "weight" of the set, for some mass density distribution. For $\lambda$, the density distribution is a constant $1$, so the weight is the length of the set. But you can also use densities that vary. For some purposes, you need negative weights. So we extend the definition a bit: if $\alpha$ is a set function and $\alpha_+, \alpha_-$ are two measures such that for all measurable sets $S, \alpha(S) = \alpha_+(S) - \alpha_-(S)$, then $$\int f\,d\alpha = \int f\,d\alpha_+ - \int f\,d\alpha_-$$

You can even have point particles: If $T = \{\tau_1, \tau_2, \dots, \tau_n\}$, we can define a measure $\mu_T(S)$ to be the number of elements of $T$ that lie in $S$. More generally, we can define $$\mu_A(S) = \sum_{k=1}^n \begin{cases}A_k&\tau_k \in S\\0&\tau_k \notin S\end{cases}$$ Then $$\int f\,d\mu_A = \sum_{k=1}^n A_kf(\tau_k)$$.

And for your application,
$$\sum_{k=1}^n A_kx(t-\tau_k) + \int_{-\tau}^0A(\eta)x(t - \eta)\,d\eta = \int_{-\tau}^0x(t - \eta)\, d\beta(\eta)$$
where the set function $\beta$ is defined by $$\beta(S) = \int_S A(t)\,d\lambda(t) + \mu_A(S)$$

Comment: This is a clean, in-depth explanation. Which really answered my question. I downloaded the suggested books, and I will look further into measure theory and functional analysis, because these parts seem interesting. But only after I finish my PhD degree, because it's really closing. Until then, thank you very much for this answer.